# Виртуальный рабочий стол windows11 вместо двух мониторов

Tags: windows, парсер, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

На работе использую 2 монитора, всё работает идеаьно. Дома хочу уйти от использования двум мониторов, в сторону виртуальных рабочих столов встроенных в Виндовс 11 . Но не могу решить проблему критичную для меня:

При использовании двум мониторов:
Можно сделать панель управления отдельно для каждого монитора. Если запустить приложение на мониторе №2, значёк приложения так же появлятся на панели управления мониора №2. И что бы ни происходило этот значёк никогда не вылезет на панель управления монитора №1. Это круто!

При использовании вертуального рабочего стола:
При запуске приложения на виртуальном рабочем столе №2, иконка приложения сначала запускается на панели управления стола №2, НО если в приложении происходит фоновое изменение (открытие окна, переключение фокуса) иконка приложения вылазиет на панель управления стола №1 и начинает раздражающе маргать.

Я использую Гугл Хроме для автоматического тестирования веб прложений, скрипт написанный на питон запускает 50 сессий Хрома с 2-3 вкладкаами в каждой сессиию. Когда использую 2 монитора я просто переношу эти окна на монитор №2 и забываю про них. При вертуальном рабочем столе, даже если приложение  запущено на столе №2 иконки Хрома постоянно лезут на панель управления монитора №1... ПОМОГИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА! Может  что в систем реестре подраправить?

Comment: Скрипт следует исправить, чтобы он использовал Headless Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

К соажалению нигде не смог найти решение. В итоге купил маленький Б/у монитор. И все не фокусные задачи перекидываю на него... Всё ещё ищу вариант использования вирт.рабочего стола т.к. на в поездках к ноутбуку второй монитор не подключишь.